# Can I apply a function to the variable in a for loop definition (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, list, iteration, user-defined-functions

**I am parsing emails with python 3.2.**

I have each email file in a list. I want to subdivide the emails into a headers list and a bodies list.

What do you think about this method?

```
def decap(self):
    # separate headers from bodies

    self.heads = []; self.bodies = []

    for email.readlines() in self.inbox.dex:                                                                                                                                     
        """The first 20 lines appended to the heads list"""
        self.heads.append(email[:10])
        """Remaining lines appended to the bodies list"""
        self.bodies.append(email[10:])
```

`self.inbox.dex` is a list of file-object

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: Well shucks, I guess the only dumb question is the one that doesn't get asked... or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there

```
...
for email in self.inbox.dex:
    email = email.readlines()
    ...
```

Also, you could do it with a list comprehension (more packed):

```
data = ((email[:10], email[10:]) for email in 
        (x.readlines() for x in self.inbox.dex))
self.heads, self.bodies = zip(*data)
```

Comment: I just popped back over to SO after making the first edit you suggested. Zip is new to me. Which method do you think would be better to handle parsing (possibly large) directories of emails?

Comment: both should be very similar.